# -1469913 days left when calculating reoccurring events in Android

Tags: android, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

For reoccurring events, I want to show the number of days left until the next occurrence in my Android calendar application.

**Example:**

```
Today: 2012-06-12
Reoccurring event: 19th June
=> 13 days left
```

In order to achieve this, I save the first occurrence in an object of data type `Calendar`:

```
private Calendar cal;
...
cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, USER_INPUT_YEAR);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, USER_INPUT_MONTH);
...
```

**To calculate the days left I use this function:**

```
public int getDaysLeft() {
    Date next = this.getNextOccurrence();
    if (next == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        long differenceInMilliseconds = next.getTime()-System.currentTimeMillis();
        double differenceInDays = (double) differenceInMilliseconds/DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
        return (int) Math.ceil(differenceInDays);
    }
}
```

**Which uses this function:**

```
public Date getNextOccurrence() {
    if (this.cal == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
        Calendar next = new GregorianCalendar();
        next.setTime(this.cal.getTime());
        next.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        if ((today.get(Calendar.MONTH) > this.cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) || ((today.get(Calendar.MONTH) == this.cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) && (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > this.cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) {
            next.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        }
        return next.getTime();
    }
}
```

**By the way, to get the initial date, I expect to find a YYYY-MM-DD value and parse it like this:**

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse(INPUT_DATE_STRING)
```

This works fine in most cases, but some users report that they see numbers such as `-1469913` as "days left". How can this happen?

I thought the date (`cal`) might be not set or invalid, but then it would show `-1` or something like this, as there are null checks in all parts, right?

`-1469913` means something like `-4027` years ago! As it is a reoccurring event, I thought the "days left" information should always be between 0 and 366. What could cause this code to produce such a number? Does this mean that `getNextOccurrence()` returns a data that is 4027 years in the past? I can't explain this behaviour.

I hope you can help me. Thank you so much in advance!

**Edit:** As it may be helpful: The wrong dates' year is always output as `1` when using `DateFormat.getDateInstance().format()`, e.g. `Jan 3, 1`. Nevertheless, the result of `getDaysLeft()` is something like 4k years.

**Edit #2:** I found out a date like `1--22199-1` is one that produces the output of "4k years left". Nevertheless, it is successfully parsed by `(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse()`. Similarly, `-1-1-1-91-` is correctly parsed as `Jan 1, 2`.

**Edit #3:** It turned out that a date as simple as "0000-01-03" was causing all the trouble. When I output the time in milliseconds it says `-62167222800000`. When I then output it to a GMT string it says `0001-01-03` - strange, isn't it? And when I set the year to `1900` the time in millis is suddenly `-122095040400000`. Why?

Comment: Joda seconded--but wouldn't this be pretty simple to debug?

Comment: Why Joda? The `Calendar` class is actually quite helpful and easy to handle, isn't it? But this is not easy to debug for me as I don't have that input data to test. But it can only be an invalid date as reoccurring events are always 366 days in the future or less, or do I dash against basic maths?

Comment: @MarcoW. Because such thing and more are trivial in Joda. I don't understand "not having input data" to test; you have enough to get something 4k years ago, so it'd seem like that might be a good starting point. Even if you didn't have that, I'm almost sure that date math is testable when properly refactored.

Comment: The problem is: I only know the output (4k years ago) but I don't know which input (date string) produced this output.

Comment: I doubt this is relevant, but: -1469913 is actually about 4024 years ago (because a year is about 365.25 days). I note that this is 2*2012. Is it possible that you've got a negated year number somewhere, with -2012 instead of 2012? (Looking at your code, I don't see an obvious way for that to happen.)

Comment: According to your hint, it seems very obvious that it's just a negated year number somewhere. So it might not be that unimportant. Please see my Edit#2 as this might be the part where the problem is caused.

Comment: Edit #3 strongly suggests you are suffering an integer overflow somewhere in the calculation, though it's not immediately apparent where.  (The numbers are too big to be a 32-bit overflow and too small to be a 64-bit one, but there could be an overflow occuring before some sort of scaling)

Comment: I thought about this, too. But as you say, there doesn't seem to be any part in the code where this could happen. So it may really be a bug in Java's `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with dates it can be really difficult to figure out those obscure errors before they happen to a user in the wild. In many cases, it can be worth your time to make a little unit test that throws a few tens of million dates in the machinery and see if any extreme answers pop up.

Also [this](http://practicallyagile.com/2009/05/java-dates-still-suck/) might be worth reading. You wont realize how bad the java date-class are before you have tried something that is way better. :)

**EDIT:** If the users give a very high input value, then there can be a number overflow when you throw your result to an integer in `getDaysLeft()`. Just keep it as a long. Or even better: Only accept sensible input value, warn the user if they input the year 20120 or something like that :)

**EDIT2:** I was wrong in my last edit, `.ceil()` protects against number overflows. To be honest I have no longer any idea how this bug can happen.

**EDIT3:** Responding to your third edit: Remember, `Date` and `Calendar` uses [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). That means that the time represented by a zero is 1970. Everything before 1970 will be represented by a negative value.

**EDIT4:** Remember that javas calendar-classes sucks. This code snippet demonstrates that the error is in fact in the Calendar-class:

```
Calendar next = new GregorianCalendar();
long date1 = -62167222800000L;
long date2 = -62135600400000L;

next.setTimeInMillis(date1);
next.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
System.out.println(next.getTimeInMillis());

next.setTimeInMillis(date2);
next.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
System.out.println(next.getTimeInMillis());
```

Output:

```
-125629491600000
1325545200000
```

It will however be very hard to track down the exact bug that causes this. The reason all those bugs remains are because fixing them might break legacy systems all over the world. My guess is that the bug originates from the inability to give negative years. This, for example, will give the output "2013":

```
Calendar next = new GregorianCalendar();
next.set(Calendar.YEAR, -2012);
System.out.println(next.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

I would simply recommend you to not allow such extreme values in your input. Decide on an acceptable span and give an error message if the value is outside of those boundaries. If you would like to handle all possible dates in some futher application, just use [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). You wont regret it :)

Comment: Thank you :) The test unit with tens of million dates is a good idea in general. But as `DateFormat.parse()` can only produce `null` or a valid `Date` object, the awkward input that causes this error can only be a date string which is interpreted as a date 4k years ago by mistake, right?

Comment: It seems as if getNextOccurrence() should return null if the date is in the past, so this alone is not enough to explain the big negative value. This also protects against the number overflow that happens if cal is set to the year of Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Sorry!!! This if statement was not in the original code, I just added while trying to debug the application and forgot to remove it again. So in the code which produced the negative numbers, this wasn't there. So `getNextOccurrence()`'s result being earlier than the current time is definitely the reason.

Comment: No, sorry, for me this question is not solved yet ;) See my latest edit.

Comment: According to your third edit ... :) Of course, I know that UNIX time is relative to 1970. But if you take a close look at those numbers, you'll see that the value for 1900 is closer to negative infinity than the value for 0000. This cannot be true!

Comment: Thank you very much :D Satisfying to see that it was not my fault.

Comment: Could you reward me the bounty, since the question has been resolved? :)

Answer (score 0):

You got negative values in days that might be because user have entered the date of next occurance which is any previous date.

I think you should calculate your daysLeft like this way,

```
            String inputDateString = "19/06/2012";
            Calendar calCurr = Calendar.getInstance();//current date
            Calendar calNext = Calendar.getInstance();// for next date
            calNext.setTime(new Date(inputDateString)); // or do set Day,Month,Year like in your Question

            if(calNext.after(calCurr)) // if the next date is after current
            {
                long timeDiff = calNext.getTimeInMillis() - calCurr.getTimeInMillis(); // time of next year if today is 15 june and some one enter 16 june for next occurance
                int daysLeft = (int) (timeDiff/DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS); // Days Left
            }
            else
            {
                long timeDiff = calCurr.getTimeInMillis() - calNext.getTimeInMillis();
                timeDiff = DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS - timeDiff; // time of next year if today is 15 june and some one enter 14 june for next occurance
                int daysLeft = (int) (timeDiff/DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS); // Days Left
            }
```

Comment: Thank you! But if you look at my latest edit to the question, you can see that this doesn't seem to be a solution.

Comment: @MarcoW. According to me you are getting negative values of daysleft is just only can be because of the wrong calculations so I am 100% sure about that that problem lies in that part of code only, have you actually tried my answer? or just overlooked it as it only does the calculations..anyways will try to analyze your code/question more and will post anything if i get.

Comment: Well, did you see my edits to the question? As you can see, the `Calendar` class seems to mess things up and calculate wrong timestamps. Otherwise, the `getNextOccurrence()` could not be earlier than today.